# How to have a project with `renv` use the user `.Rprofile` as well as the project `.Rprofile`?

Tags: r, renv

I have a lot of tidyverse-recommended settings in my user `.Rprofile` that I noticed are not being used inside projects with `renv` because `renv` creates a project-specific `.Rprofile`.

Is there a way to configure `renv` to always use the user `.Rprofile` (i.e. source it) in addition to the project `.Rprofile`? I don't understand this page on [renv user-level configuration](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/config.html).

I know this is less reproducible but I'm not placing anything in my user `.Rprofile` that would go against reproducibility except for something like

```
Sys.setenv("_R_CHECK_LENGTH_1_CONDITION_" = "true")
```

as recommended by Hadley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as the page you linked says, you need to set the option `renv.config.user.profile` to `TRUE`.  It defaults to `FALSE`.

There are two ways to do that.

1. Run `options(renv.config.user.profile = TRUE)` in R before doing anything in `renv`.  Putting that line in your `.Rprofile` file should do this.
2. Set the environment variable `RENV_CONFIG_USER_PROFILE=TRUE` outside of R.  How you do that depends on your system (Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc.).

Comment: For 1., do you mean each putting it in the project's `.Rprofile`? Is there any way to avoid doing this for each project?

Comment: Number 2 is likely a global choice, as is the "site profile" file.  See `?Startup` for where R looks for that.

Comment: Thanks. I only knew how to do Number 2 above with the .Renviron file which is where a package I use (qualtRics) relies on secrets. Hence I followed your comment and found the SITE file by running `R.home(component = "home")` following `?Startup`.